# Composer Autoload gives error "Class not found"

Tags: php, composer-php

I am having some issues with composer's psr-4 autoloading. I have a project structure that looks like this

```
Project
- src/
- - Utils/
- - - ID/
- - - - IDInterface.php
- - - - ID.php
- tests/
- - IDTest.php
- ... (other stuff)
```

Then, in my composer.json file, I have a psr-4 autoload that looks like this.

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
             "Project\\": "src"
        }
    }
```

Then in my test class (IDTest.php) I have the following

```
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Project\Utils\ID;

class IDTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testConstructFromString()
    {
        $id = new ID("foo");
        $this->assertSame("foo", $id->value());
    }
}

?>
```

When I run the test, however, I get this error:

```
1) IDTest::testConstructFromString
Error: Class 'Project\Utils\ID' not found
```

It seems to be pointing to the line:

```
$id = new ID("foo");
```

which indicates that the autoload is not working as I expect it to.

For reference, the ID class looks something like this:

```
<?php

namespace Javelin\Util;

use Javelin\Utils\IDInterface;
use Javelin\Util\IllegalArgumentException;

class ID implements IDInterface{...}
?>
```

I tried running `composer dump-autoload` to see if I just needed to update the autoloader. But, sadly, the problem persists.

Comment: `ID.php` file defines `Javelin\Util\ID` class in file where `Project\Utils\ID\ID` should be defined, and you're requesting `Project\Utils\ID`. Nothing match here, you need to really clean it and decide what namespace your class should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
use Project\Utils\ID\ID;
```

`Project\Utils\ID` - namespace.
`Project\Utils\ID\ID` - class.

Comment: Okay, that fixed it. Why was the namespace Project\Utils\ID? I thought I specified in the class definition that the namespace was only Project\Utils, which should have meant Project\Utils\ID was the class? Thanks a lot for the help. :)